# How do I pass more than one parameter in Hibernate createSQLQuery()?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to call a Stored Procedure using Hibernate. I can't seem to find how I pass more than one parameter?

I know with one parameter you can do this:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
...
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL StoredProcedureTest(:parameter)")
.addEntity(DBModel.class)
.setParameter("parameter", parameter);

ArrayList<DBModel> results = query.list();
```

I notice there is a `.setParameters(Object object[], Type[] types)` option but can't find many examples of this at all and don't see how this would work.

What do I do if I need more than one parameter? Can I do this in the same way?

Comment: have yo tested this CALL StoredProcedureTest(:parameter, :param2, :param3) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call setParameter another time:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL StoredProcedureTest(:parameter1, :parameter2)")
   .addEntity(DBModel.class)
   .setParameter("parameter1", parameter1)
   .setParameter("parameter2", parameter2);
```

Comment: Ahh yes. I'm just getting to grips with this whole Java thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can always continue the line:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL StoredProcedureTest(:parameter, :parameter2)")
.addEntity(DBModel.class)
.setParameter("parameter", parameter).setParameter("parameter2", parameter2);
```